# How do I find the point on a google map that's closest to me?

Tags: android, google-api

I am writing an Android-application that is supposed to download a bunch of addresses from my SQL-server, reverse geocode them, compare them all to my current location and return the one that is closest to me, not geometrically, but the one that I am the shortest driving distance from.

I have managed to get the reversed geocoding to work, but when I run my program a few times, I hit the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT on google. Needless to say, there are quite a few addresses in my database.

I understand that I could do this the quick and dirty way and just see which address is nearest to me by comparing the latitude and longitude of my current position and that of my addresses as opposed to comparing it to the actual driving distance. The problem with this is that this application will be used in a region where there are quite a lot of lakes to drive around and using that method will likely return quite a few stupid results.

How can I keep this from happening over and over? Can I present google with a view of all my addresses and just do a comparison once? I really need help with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you will have to query a routing service (not necessarily Google Maps, to my knowledge also [Cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com/products/navi-studio) provides you with routing; there definitely are more) to get driving directions to each of the Points Of Interest around you and then select the closest one. This is a very bad practice, as you are very limited with the request amount.

According to the [Google Maps API TOS](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) (paragraph 10.1.3) you are not always allowed to do that.

What I did in a similar case was to store the coordinates for all POI, and look up the closest ones just by range of lat/lng.

Comment: I'll look into Cloudmate, they might have different terms of use than google. Thanks!

Comment: They do, as they use OpenStreetMaps, but they have not nearly as much information about POIs and street addresses. Probably the best reverse geocoding I've found so far was from an ESRI provider, but it's a pain as they don't offer anything global.